# How do I get .remove() to work with the window object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like the `.remove()` method to fire when the browser width hits a threshold and add it back when it's not.

I guess I could use a media query but just wanted to quickly handle it with jQuery.

```
;(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w < 768) {
            console.log(w);
            $('#avon-nav br').remove();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You'd probably have to utilize the 'resize' event and perform this logic in the handler. This will only fire when the page initially loads. If I load the page, then change the size of my window, this won't have an effect. For the record, I'd recommend CSS media query as well but if you want to go with jQuery that would be my approach. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: you should use a media query

Comment: honestly it's quicker to handle it with a media query. Not to mention that if you remove the `<br>` it is hard to put them back

Comment: Thanks guys, I think you've convinced me. Just wanted to give it a try...

Comment: Your questions says `toggle()` but your code doesn't use `toggle()`

Comment: @Juan, Thanks I made the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add a resize event to the window. Take a look at this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 768) {
        $('#avon-nav br').hide();
    } else {
        $('#avon-nav br').show();
    }
});
```

I replace toggle with hide and show because it acted different depending on the initial window size. Here's the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/o6zqkq42/1/).